# Evaluating a nested log integral

Tags: integration

> **Question:**$$\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {\log\log\frac 1x}{(1+x)^2}=\frac 12\log\frac {\pi}2-\frac {\gamma}2$$

I’ve had some practice with similar integrals, but this one eludes me for some reason. I first made the transformation $x\mapsto-\log x$ to get rid of the nested log. Therefore$$\mathfrak{I}=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\,\frac {e^{-x}\log x}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$$
The inside integrand can be rewritten as an infinite series to get$$\mathfrak{I}=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}(n+1)(-1)^n\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\, e^{-x(n+1)}\log x$$The inside integral, I thought, could be evaluated by differentiating the gamma function to get$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dt\, e^{-t(n+1)}\log t=-\frac {\gamma}{n+1}-\frac {\log(n+1)}{n+1}$$
However, when I simplify everything and split the sum, neither sum converges. If we consider it as a Cesaro sum, then I know for sure that$$\sum\limits_{n\geq0}(-1)^n=\frac 12$$Which eventually does give the right answer. But I’m not sure if we’re quite allowed to do that especially because in a general sense, neither sum converges.

Answer (score 4):

By the dominated convergence theorem we have
$$ \mathfrak{I} = \lim_{r \nearrow 1} I(r) \, ,$$
where for $r \in (0,1)$ we have defined
$$ I(r) = \int\limits_0^1 \mathrm{d} x\,\frac {\log\log\frac 1x}{(1+r x)^2} \, . $$
With this regularisation interchanging summation and integration is actually justified and your calculations lead to
$$ I(r) = - \gamma \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-r)^n - \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-r)^n \log(1+n) \equiv I_1 (r) + I_2(r) \, . $$
The first sum is easy:
$$ I_1(r) = - \frac{\gamma}{1+r} \, , $$
so $\lim_{r \nearrow 1} I_1(r) = - \frac{\gamma}{2}$ .

For the second sum we can write
\begin{align}
I_2(r) &= \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-r)^n \log(n) \\
&= \frac{1}{2r} \sum_{k=1}^\infty [2 r^{2k} \log(2k) - r^{2k-1} \log(2k-1) - r^{2k+1} \log(2k+1)] \\
&= \frac{1}{2r} \sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{2k} \left[\log\left(\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\right) + (1-r) \log(2k+1) - \frac{1}{r} (1-r) \log(2k-1)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2r} \sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{2k} \left[\log\left(\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\right) + (1-r)^2 \log(2k+1)\right] \, .
\end{align}
The second term can be estimated by
\begin{align}
\frac{(1-r)^2}{2r} \sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{2k}  \log(2k+1) &\leq \frac{(1-r)^2}{2r^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n} r^{n} \\
&= \frac{(1-r)^2}{2r^2} \operatorname{Li}_{-1/2} (r) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 r^2} \sqrt{1-r} + \mathcal{O}  \left((1-r)^{3/2}\right)
\end{align}
as $r \nearrow 1$. The asymptotic behaviour of the polylogarithm can be deduced from the series given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations) (the second one below 2.). Now we can use the monotone convergence theorem and Wallis' product to find
$$ \lim_{r \nearrow 1} I_2 (r) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \log\left(\frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-1}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \, . $$

Therefore 
$$ \mathfrak{I} = \frac{1}{2} \left[\log \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \gamma\right]$$
as claimed.

Comment: Confirmed by *Mathematica*:  $\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\gamma \right)$