# Definite integral $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{2}+1}\right)\ln\left(\operatorname{arctanh}x\right)dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

Prove the following closed form:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{2}+1}\right)\ln\left(\operatorname{arctanh}x\right)dx=\ln\pi-\gamma-\left(2-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ln2-\pi\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\sqrt{2\pi}\right).$$

I had discovered this while attempting to prove a [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456398/calculate-this-integral-containing-log-inverse-tanh-int-01-x-arctan-x-ln) when I attempted to integrate both sides of

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)\arctan(x)\ln(\operatorname{arctanh}(x)) = 2x\arctan(x)\ln(\operatorname{arctanh}(x))+\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)\ln(\operatorname{arctanh}(x))-\frac{\arctan(x)}{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)}.$$

That post was nine months ago and I didn't keep a systematic record of my process. I'm sure I could figure it out if I dug through my old work, but now I'm mostly curious to see how others in the community would attack this.

Comment: I added some context in the body of my post. I hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: I don't really see why this was closed, it is a closed-form integral and an interesting problem for people to try

Comment: Isn't this technically an improper integral because at $x=0$, $\tanh(x)=0$ and $\ln (0)$ is undefined?

Comment: You are correct @CSquared . I will modify the tag.

Comment: Wow, I spent an hour trying to figure out what was wrong with my evaluation, but I just realized: It's $\ln(\operatorname{arctanh} x)$, not just $\operatorname{arctanh} x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=-\int _0^1\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\:\ln \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
$$=-\int _0^1\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\ln \left(\ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\right)\:dx-\ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\int _0^1\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=-4\int _0^1\frac{t\ln \left(-\ln \left(t\right)\right)}{\left(1+t^2\right)\left(1+t\right)^2}\:dt-\ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-1\right)$$
$$=-2\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(-\ln \left(t\right)\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt+2\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(-\ln \left(t\right)\right)}{\left(1+t\right)^2}\:dt-\ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-1\right)$$
$$=-2\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{1+e^{-2x}}\:e^{-x}\:dx+2\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}\:e^{-x}\:dx+\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left(2\right)-\ln \left(2\right)$$
$$=-2\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^k\:\int _0^{\infty }e^{-x\left(2k+1\right)}\ln \left(x\right)\:dx+2\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}\:e^{-x}\:dx+\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left(2\right)-\ln \left(2\right)$$
$$=2\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^k\:\left(\frac{\ln \left(2k+1\right)+\gamma }{2k+1}\right)+2\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}\:e^{-x}\:dx+\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left(2\right)-\ln \left(2\right)$$
$$=2\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k\ln \left(2k+1\right)}{2k+1}+2\gamma \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{2k+1}+2\underbrace{\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^2}\:e^{-x}\:dx}_{K}+\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left(2\right)-\ln \left(2\right)$$
$$\boxed{I=-2\beta '\left(1\right)+\frac{\gamma \pi }{2}+\ln \left(\pi \right)-\gamma +\frac{\pi }{2}\ln \left(2\right)-2\ln \left(2\right)}$$
Where $\displaystyle \beta '\left(s\right)$ is the derivative of the Dirichlet beta function.

Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853819/evaluating-a-nested-log-integral) for the integral $K$.

Comment: Result can be verified via wolfram, [direct computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+-%28%281-x%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29+ln%28arctanh%28x%29%29), the [result found](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2*Limit%5BD%5Bdirichletbeta%28s%29%2C+%7Bs%2C+1%7D%5D%2C+%7Bs+-%3E+1%7D%5D%2B%28eulergamma*pi%29%2F2%2Bln%28pi%29-eulergamma%2Bpi%2F2+ln%282%29-2ln%282%29).